# jQuery not working in IE8 and less and iOS5 and less

Tags: jquery

I am developing a jQuery fallback for [this CSS3-powered accordion.](https://www.msu.edu/~mirirfan/maurers/)

However, upon testing it I noticed that it does not work in iOS5 or less or IE8 - IE6. Meaning, the panels / slides of the accordion do not open up / slideDown.

I asked some people on the jQuery forums, but they are stumped on why its not working.
One person said it may be due to me using the :animated in my jQuery, which IE and iOS do not support. But said person did not have an alternative method of rewriting my code without it.

What I am trying to achieve is to get the corresponding  to slideDown once the input (checkbox) is checked / label is clicked and then slideUp when the input is unchecked / label is clicked again.

Can someone please help me fix my code so that it works in IE and iOS ?

I would sincerely appreciate any and all help.

Thank you in Advance!

**EDIT: I am looking for a jQuery solution using my HTML5 markup.**

Answer (score 0):

I know it's fancy CSS3 and all, but if that's the kind of God-awful unsemantic markup required to make that happen, I wouldn't bother. 4 lines of jquery, and you're done:

Markup:

```
<dl class="menu">
    <dt><a href="#">About Us</a></dt>
    <dd>
        <p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.</p>
    </dd>
    <dt><a href="#">How We Work</a></dt>
    <dd>
        <p>Like you, I used to think the world was this great place where everybody lived by the same standards I did, then some kid with a nail showed me I was living in his world, a world where chaos rules not order, a world where righteousness is not rewarded. That's Cesar's world, and if you're not willing to play by his rules, then you're gonna have to pay the price.</p>
    </dd>
    <dt><a href="#">References</a></dt>
    <dd>
        <p>You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind. Like it knows it killed the world once and got a taste for murder. After the avalanche, it took us a week to climb out. Now, I don't know exactly when we turned on each other, but I know that seven of us survived the slide... and only five made it out. Now we took an oath, that I'm breaking now. We said we'd say it was the snow that killed the other two, but it wasn't. Nature is lethal but it doesn't hold a candle to man. </p>
    </dd>
    <dt><a href="#">Contact Us</a></dt>
    <dd>
        <p>You see? It's curious. Ted did figure it out - time travel. And when we get back, we gonna tell everyone. How it's possible, how it's done, what the dangers are. But then why fifty years in the future when the spacecraft encounters a black hole does the computer call it an 'unknown entry event'? Why don't they know? If they don't know, that means we never told anyone. And if we never told anyone it means we never made it back. Hence we die down here. Just as a matter of deductive logic.</p>
    </dd>
</dl>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('.menu > dt > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next('dd').slideToggle();
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XNXRf/10/)

You can probably adapt that to your markup, but God, why would you?

Comment: @JamWaffles Yeah, agreed. 

But, how is it bad markup? its just HTML5 and it is semantic HTML5. This is just how to do an accordion in html5 and css3.

Comment: 1. Inputs without a form and no destination for that input data. Inputs are used to collect data, but no data is being collected.
2. `<section>` element being used for styling purposes rather than to divide content into logical groups.

Comment: 3. Inaccessible navigation. How are users with screen readers supposed to interpret all those checkboxes?
4. Inefficient cost/benefit ratio. You're using dozens of lines of CSS3 and Modernizr to accomplish what you could do with 4 lines of jQuery.